# What is the meaning of the word "work" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

This is the sentence I've got problems with. It's a bit dated translation but I believe one of the suggestions I listed below is applicable here.

"What was it had happened to **work** this revolution
in him?"

(these are definitions from Google dictionary)

1.
bring into a specified emotional state.
"Harold had worked himself into a minor rage"
2.
produce as a result.
"with a dash of blusher here and there, you can work miracles"

Comment: Which one do you think works better, and why?

Comment: Understand ***work*** here as ***cause** [to come about*. The subject ("him") has experienced some kind of metaphoric "revolution" (i.e. - a massive change, perhaps alluding to a 180° "half-turn" so he's metaphorically "facing" in the opposite direction to before). The sentence asks what might have happened to *cause* that change.

Comment: Not the question, but the phrasing "what was it had happened" could be replaced by "what had happened".

Comment: Crime and Punishment again. Work used this way was quite common in the 19th Century - e.g. I knew a wicked man but God worked a great change in him. This is the 1913 translation I think?

Answer (score 3):

The second definition ("produce as a result") fits the meaning here.

The word "cause" would also work here, and have the same meaning:

> What was it had happened to cause this revolution in him?